# Autocomplete in Qt Creator: how to add header files for a cmake project

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator, qmake

If I am making a Qt Creater project using cmake, rather than qmake, how can I tell Qt Creator where to look for header files for autocompletion? In CMakeLists.txt, I can specify where to look for heading in compilation, but Qt Creator will not read this until I build the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can make headers show up in CMake by including them in the sources list for a target you're building, alongside the source files. This works for files that are part of your project.

For header files somewhere on your system where the compiler can find them, I'd guess that running CMake (to generate the Makefile) should be enough for Qt Creator to find them.